# How to extract string from python list

Tags: python, string

Feels like this should be easy, but I can't find the right keywords to search for the answer.

**Given** `['"https://container.blob.core.windows.net/"']` as results from a python statement...

...how do I extract only the URL and drop the `['"` and `"']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
a = ['"https://container.blob.core.windows.net/"']
result = a[0].replace("\"","")
print(result)
```

Result:

```
'https://container.blob.core.windows.net/'
```

As a python string.

Answer (score 5):

You want the first element of the list without the first and last char

```
>>> l[0][1:-1]
'https://container.blob.core.windows.net/'
```

Comment: Wow! The smallest amount of code possible. Nice! This worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about using regex??

```py
In [35]: url_list = ['"https://container.blob.core.windows.net/"']

In [36]: url = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\), ]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', url_list[
    ...: 0])[0]

In [37]: print(url)
https://container.blob.core.windows.net/
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with other solutions because the amount of code was less.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting first element using `list[0]` and remove the single quotes from it using `replace()` or `strip()` ?

```
 print(list[0].replace("'",""))
```

**OR**

```
print(list[0].strip("'")
```

Comment: I went with your second option as it was the smallest amount of code. Edited a bit with: `url = str(blob_url[0].strip('"'))`. Had to strip out the doublequote and convert to string. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @SeaDude glad it helps you somehow, Happy Coding!